# How can I get this unmapped port to work like a mapped port?

Tags: docker

Note: This question is more about why the mapped port might behave differently and how I might be able to correct it, than it is about the specific app I'm trying to run.

I'm trying to get this tunnel/reverse proxy server to work without mapping ports. It works when I map one of the ports to a host port, but doesn't when I don't.

First, it works when I run it like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 83 -p 85:85 jpillora/chisel server --port 83 -reverse
```

docker ps:

```
...0.0.0.0:85->85/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32853->83/tcp
```

I start the client like this: `chisel client example.com:32853 R:85:localhost:8000`. When I go to http://example.com:85/ and I see my localhost port 8000.

This works great!

However, I do not want to map port 85. I want Docker to assign it for me so I can run as many as I want without having to think about port assignments.

In this case I would run the server like this:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 83 -p 85 jpillora/chisel server --port 83 -reverse
```

docker ps:

```
...0.0.0.0:32853->83/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32854->85/tcp
```

Now, I start the client like this: `chisel client example.com:32853 R:32854:localhost:8000`.

I would expect to be able to swap out the http port with the one assigned for port `85`, however, I get no response when requesting: http://example.com:32854/

So why would the mapped port work and the unmapped not, and is there anything I could try to make it work without mapping?

Comment: If it's a reverse proxy shouldn't you have only one port mapped and access other services throw the proxy. So if you don't map the port 85 but still try to access the port 85 what happen ?

Comment: I updated the post to word that better. The first job of this app (Chisel) is to be a tunnel, from the user's local system (behind a firewall) to the public server. Then there's an option to make the server a reverse proxy, serving traffic on port 85, with the source coming from the tunnel. (83)